# Can you reanimate a slain undead with Animated Dead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, undead, necromancy

If you slay an undead creature can you cast animate dead on the corpse to bring it back as a zombie or skeleton?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*animate dead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#animate-dead) [necro] (*Player's Handbook* 198—9) says, "This spell turns the bones or bodies of **dead** creatures into undead skeletons or zombies that follow your spoken commands" (emphasis mine). Also, as [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114179/8610) says, the spell *animate dead* parenthetically says, "A destroyed skeleton or zombie can’t be animated again," making it so a lone corpse can't become a zombie repeatedly, for instance, but the question of animating the remains of, for example, a ghoul or wight (*ahem*) remains.

When reduced to 0 hit points, the typical creature that possesses the type [undead](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_undeadtype&alpha=U) (*Monster Manual* 317) is destroyed. The game never properly defines *destroyed*, but even if the case is made that *dead* and *destroyed* are—I dunno—*secretly* synonyms, an animated dead creature "can be created only from a mostly intact corpse or skeleton" (199), and I suspect only the most generous DM will rule that a destroyed undead creature's form is mostly intact.

That said, if the DM *does* rule that a creature that possess the type undead keeps the condition dead upon its destruction *and* the DM rules that the creature's destruction leaves the resultant corpse largely intact *and* the creature wasn't previously animated *via* the spell *animate dead*, then—finally!—the *animate dead* spell *can* be used on that largely intact dead *and* destroyed *and* not-previously-animated-by-*animate*-*dead* creature… *if* sticking to the core rules.

Beyond the core rules (like this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114121/8610) mentions), *Libris Mortis* on Undead Healing says

> What would disable or render unconscious a living creature destroys an undead creature beyond recall. (In game terms, when an undead is reduced to 0 hit points or less, it is permanently destroyed.) No aid, magical or mundane, is sufficient to restore the undead to its previous state of animation. (10)

This makes it clear—outside obvious exceptions like the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell *revive undead* [necro] (*Spell Compendium* 175—6)—that the spell *animate dead* can't animate a creature that possesses the type undead that's been destroyed.

Comment: We can infer from the existence of a higher level spell that restores undead that animated that should not work this way.

Comment: @ThreeDiag I considered that, but the spell *revive undead* revives back that *specific* destroyed undead while *animate dead* typically makes a *new* skeleton or zombie. That is, casting *revive undead* on a destroyed ghoul sorcerer 12 will get back *that* ghoul sorcerer 12, but casting *animate dead* on that destroyed ghoul—if the DM agrees that's even possible—will probably just yield a boring ol' zombie.

Comment: "Undeath to Death" might be the best test case for your hypothetical. Even that says that the undead are "destroyed" though.

Answer (score 2):

The [animate dead](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#animate-dead) spell can't target a destroyed undead since it only target a dead creature, not a destroyed one (Yes, there is a difference). The Libris Mortis talk about this in details but you can't reanimate an undead that was destroyed (Zombies and skeletons are the main example). The gist of it would be "You can't kill what is already dead, you destroy it."

To make use of a former undead, you should use the Revive Undead spell (Libris Mortis/Spell Compendium).

Comment: I disagree with your claim that a destroyed undead creature is not still also a dead creature. Can you back that up?

Comment: @KRyan LM pg10: "In game terms, when an undead is reduced to 0 hit points or less, it is permanently destroyed. No aid, magical or mundane, is sufficient to restore the undead to its previous state of animation.
Since they are already dead, undead that are destroyed cannot
be returned to existence through raise dead or reincarnate."

If they can't be used in raise dead and reincarnate, I believe they don't qualify as dead creatures after being destroyed.

Comment: That literally says “since they are already dead.”

Comment: @KRyan Yes, at its previous state, they are dead, then destroyed and can't be used in a raise dead spell. 
For a living being its previous state would be alive, then dead and a valid target for a raise dead spell.

Comment: You still have provided nothing that says an undead creature, destroyed or not, isn’t also dead. My initial assumption would be that it is, and I (and Stack Exchange more generally) require evidence showing this assumption false.

Comment: @KRyan The target of a [Raise Dead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/raiseDead.htm) spell is a _dead creature_, if it does not qualifies as a target of the aforementioned spell, it is not a _dead creature_. Spells like [True Ressurection](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/trueResurrection.htm) explicitly says that they can ressurect a destroyed undead as a living being, but not a normal just dead undead. Specific beats general like always.

Comment: (There's also an ugly, never-resolved contradiction between the spells *resurrection et al* and the creature type undead that's the subject of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46042/8610).)

Comment: I think that in some cases it could be acceptable, like: if body quality is "good enough" and "destroying" or slaining didn't made it unusable... which probably, in general, happens very rarely :-) Still, we can't completely rule out some homebrew Frankenstein, who makes the undead whole again and animates them. It could actually be cool, keeping some severed limbs together with metal or wooden reinforcements, making something into kind of medieval mecha-undeads ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is definitely not lesser undead, straight from the players handbook.

First paragraph page 199.  Yes 3.5e, and 3e and 2e.

> This spell turns the bones or bodies of dead creatures into undead skeletons or zombies that follow your spoken commands. The undead can follow you, or they can remain in an area and attack any creature (or just a specific kind of creature) entering the place. They remain animated until they are destroyed. (A destroyed skeleton or zombie can’t be animated again.)

I would also argue a creature that is destroyed has no body.
From Wish on page 302

> Revive the dead. A wish can bring a dead creature back to life by duplicating a resurrection spell. A wish can revive a dead creature whose body has been destroyed, but the task takes two wishes, one to recreate the body and another to infuse the body with life again. A wish cannot prevent a character who was brought back to life from losing an experience level.

Comment: It would help you to quote the *Player’s Handbook*, since I for one don’t see it there. Note that the question is about D&D 3.5e, ***not*** the latest D&D 5e. The D&D 5e *Player’s Handbook* does indeed say that, but it’s not relevant to D&D 3.5e. The D&D 3.5e *Player’s Handbook* does not say that, as far as I can tell (feel free to prove me wrong with a quote and page number).

Comment: If that second paragraph there *is* a quote, please indicate that by putting it in a quotebox (`>` at the start of the paragraph).

Comment: The second paragraph was indeed a quote,  edited now to reflect that and to add something else I found.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how the four people answering here missed that. Thanks for pointing it out, and sorry I doubted you. Though I’d point out—as HeyICanChan did in another comment—that the existence of higher-power spells reviving undead, whether it be *wish* or *revive undead*, doesn’t quite demonstrate all that much because those are much more powerful, returning an undead creature to its previous state rather than turning it into a generic zombie or skeleton.

Comment: @KRyan I think you didn't grasped what Cro says. I assume he says 'destroyed' in the "when reduced to 0 hit points, undead creature is destroyed" (from undead type) and  'destroyed' in "dead creature whose body has been destroyed..." (from Wish) is the same destroyed so you can't cast Animate Dead on both. It's not true, but I think it was the vision of this answer's author. Of course, authoritative clarification is welcome!

Comment: @annoyingimp Ooh, I misread that. That seems more like *wish* as a replacement for *true resurrection*, I don’t think “destroyed” there necessarily has anything to do with undeath.

Comment: @KRyan It doesn't have. You can restore destroyed undead to life with a single Wish (just emulate resurrection), but you need two to handle the destroyed mentioned in Wish itself. I just think reasoning outlined in my previous comment was Cro's point, not the capability of higher-power spells to restore destroyed undead to undeath.

Comment: @annoyingimp Using *wish* as the basis of defining destroyed means *revive undead* can only be cast in really weird circumstances: "The body of the undead to be revived must be whole" yet the spell "restore[s] animation to an undead creature destroyed by hit point loss" (*Spell Compendium* 176). Small loss, I guess, but important for some.

Answer (score -1):

Rules as written, animate dead works on a dead humanoid, not an dead undead. So no.

That said, I and, many DMs chose to ignore this distinction and let people animate anything they can. There are animated undead hands in the monster manual so there is a precedent that you don't even need an intact body.

In conclusion: DM's discretion.

Comment: That’s false, *animate dead* works on “One or more corpses touched,” with no reference made to the initial creature type.

Comment: PHB, Animate Dead sentence two "Choose a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium of Small humanoid within Range, "

Comment: Question's about *3.5e* not *5e.*

Comment: That will teach me to double check the tags.