# Is it possible for undead to procreate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I know D&D 3.5 has a wide array of spells and items that can do pretty much anything imaginable. What i want to ask is are there any spells or magic items that will allow an undead to have a child without stopping being an undead permanently? I am willing to accept answer that involve the undead creature who wants to have a kid gouging out a part of his soul(In the form of experience gained by killing good adventurers) and creating a body for it through the creature created in this way should possess an intellegence score and have a free will. I am also happy to accept any answer that involves the undead temporarily becoming human in order to impregnate someone.

It doesn't matter if the child is living or undead as long as it has it's own free will.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to want to [perpetuate an aristocracy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51657/8610), would you?

Comment: For *any* undead, for *every* undead, or for a *specific* undead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [half-vampire template](http://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/templates/halfvampire.shtml), which appears to come from Libris Mortis:

> In rare circumstances, a vampire that has recently consumed a significant quantity of blood gains the ability to breed successfully with living humanoids or monstrous humanoids, creating half-vampire offspring.

The other obvious choice would be for an undead to kill a living creature, which generally causes the slain creature to reanimate as an undead.  Some undead, such as ghouls, do not control the newly created undead.  I'm guessing that you wouldn't consider such a creature to be a "child" in any useful sense.

An undead might attempt the "polymorph into a living creature and get something pregnant" approach, but this would fail unless they used the ninth-level spell *shapechange*.  Any lesser spell inherits the following rules text from *alter self*:

> Any part of the body or piece of equipment that is separated from the whole reverts to its true form.

The *shapechange* spell explicitly does not have this disadvantage.  On the other hand, *shapechange* only lasts ten minutes per level, and I assume that the pregancy would fail if it wore off.

One last approach might be to use *polymorph any object* to transform a piece of an undead into a child.  This should work well until the child is hit by a sufficiently strong *dispel magic* spell.

Comment: +1 for the template, its an excellent find but I wouldn't count on the poly/shapechange myself