# How can I undo the physical effects of aging while keeping the mental effects?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard

In DnD 3.5e, is there any way that I can take an "venerable" character, which takes a -6 to all physical stats and +3 to all mental stats, and UNDO the physical stat losses? This character is a level 9 wizard.

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37094/8610)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

The *Polymorph* spell will give you a shiny new set of physical stats (but will not change your hp - that is what *False Life* is for).  Presumably also you will be a Dragon or a Troll or something fancy.

The *Reincarnation* spell makes you young again, but presumably, removes the aging bonuses (nothing about this is explicit, but uh, hrm).

Be a Dragonwrought Kobold (and very, very old) for mental bonuses with no physical penalties.

Use *Astral Seed* and shenanigans to have your body 'reform' as that of, for example, a Great Wyrm Gold Dragon.

Have a higher leveled caster cast *Polymorph Any Object* on you to change you into a younger version of yourself/humanoid race of your choice.  Duration is permanent, so although it can be dispelled, you won't be old even when you're asleep.

Become a Necropolitan, and never worry about that pesky Con score ever again.

Wait a bit, and then, become a Lich.  Ergo, etc.

I can't recall anything that explicitly says that intelligent undead don't suffer physical aging penalties but benefit from mental aging gains, but it seems pretty reasonable.

Even getting bit by a vampire or lycanthrope is not a terrible idea if you don't plan to gain levels much (short duration campaign).

If you have Persist Cheese active, persisting a single buff like *Bite of the Weretiger* will trivially solve a lot of those issues by hugely boosting your physical stats and toughness.

If you want my advice, though, roll with having poor physical stats and make party members carry you around and stuff.  Sounds hilarious and fun as hell to roleplay.

Comment: I ended up going with the last decision for roleplay purposes, but I will always keep a polymorph spell prepared. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> **Last Breath**, *Spell Compendium*
>
> **School**: Transmutation
> **Class/Level**: Druid/4
> **Components**: V, S
> **Casting Time**: 1 standard action
> **Range**: Touch
> **Target**: Dead creature touched
> **Duration**: Instantaneous
> **Saving Throw**: None
> **Spell Resistance**: Yes (harmless)
>
> **Description**: Last breath restores life to a recently deceased creature, creating a new body for the returning spirit to inhabit. However, the spell must be cast within 1 round of the victim's death. This spell functions like reincarnate (PH 270), except that the reincarnated creature receives no level loss, no Constitution loss, and no loss of spells. The creature has -1 hit points (but is stable).
>
> **Material Components**: Rare oils and unguents worth a total of at least 500 gp, spread over the remains.

You can use *Last Breath* to reincarnate without CON or HD loss. Unlike *Reincarnate*, you can spam *Last Breath* indefinitely.

If you have time, you could also multiclass into Green Star Adept (Complete Arcane) and become a construct after 10 levels, or into Monk or Druid and lose all age penalties after 17 or 15 levels, respectively.

Comment: Can you discuss reincarnation's effects on mental stats?

Comment: New racial modifiers if your race changes, otherwise none, I think.

Comment: According to the [SRD page for *Reincarnate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reincarnate.htm), racial modifiers for the new body only affect physical stats.

Comment: The problem is, it either doesn't affect age-related modifiers or changes them all to 'young'.