# Virtual Immortality

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-3e

I'm looking for ways to make PC's and NPC's virtually immortal. I know that EVERYTHING can be killed in one way or another, but that's not where I'm headed with this discussion.

Elves have extremely long lifespans but do eventually die of old age...

Elans are virtually immortal, and self sustaining due to their psionics.

There are a couple of prestige classes (I wish I could think of their names), one that grants a unicorn and one that grants a dragon, and the character ages at the same rate as their companion, and hence virtual immortality.

Upon reaching Epic levels, one can take a feat to extend their natural lifespan exponentially every time they take it, so again virtual immortality...

I've heard of a spell that stops aging (I wish I could remember the name of the spell), but I can't recal it at the moment, and that grants virtual immortality as well. And Reincarnation can allow a form of immortality, if limited...

Becoming undead nets you virtual immortality.

Becoming a God grants you immortality.

Are there any other ways, classes I'm missing, spells, tricks, etc. that would/could grant characters to have EXTREME ages?

Comment: I suggest making this *Pathfinder* specific. As it is, it's too broad and a [possible duplicate.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37092/8610)

Comment: That does toutch on some of what I'm asking in a small way by the main question, and slightly larger ways in the following answers, but it's not very consise, and doesnt answer the questions I'm looking to answer, or for the thing's I'm proposing... Yes, some of the spells/tricks I mentioned are listed, Elans are listed, but I'm looking for more, other ways to achieve this. I gave examples of 2 prestige classes, and a feat that could help this... are there other ways?

Comment: There are tons. That's why the question really *does* need narrowing: "What's the [earliest, easiest, least expensive--pick *one*] way a PC can achieve immortality given [these resources--and make a list]?" There's no *answer* for this question as it stands, only nonspecific lists. Make it a problem to be solved: What's *preventing* the character's immortality? A lack of funds, a lack of time, limited textual resources, a ruthless DM?

Comment: I'm sorry Can Chan, but I'm not looking for ONE specific method to this. I'm DMing a game where I would like to introduce virtual immortality in other ways than just being Elans, Warforged/Constructs, or Undead. The earliest possible ways besides race would be nice, but I'm intentionally trying to not limit peoples resourcefulness in answering this question. There are classes, feats, and tricks that can allow for this... No one person need know them all. If each person that comments contributes 1 thing, that can grow to be a big list, fast, and thats fine by me.

Comment: @AOKost That's really not how questions are meant to work.

Comment: The shere number of examples I gave should cut the number of possible answers down dramatically. I know that Kiss of the Ages will stop one from aging, but it's a 9th level spell if I remember correctly. A few minor work arounds from the possible duplicate page that Hey I Can Chan posted I hadn't known about, but many of the thing's I myself listed were not listen on that page. Is it not bad form to resurect dead pages?

Comment: @AOKost unfortunately, Stack Exchange's format is not good for your question. I suggest you to ask it in a D&D forum (there are many), and use SE for more specific questions, where a right answer can be choosen.

Comment: @AOKost The Stackexchange format expects a question to have an answer. A single, acceptable answer. There is no one answer to your question, that's why it's a bad fit for the format. You could for example ask for the fastest way for a certain character to gain immortality. Or the cheapest. That is a clear question that will have a clear answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for being argumentative and obstinate about my questions, but I've seen plenty of blatant open ended questions on this forum. 'How do I deal with this?' 'How do I do that?' 'What is the best way to do this?' All of which have no single answer, as there is no single 'right' answer. This question is little different. If it will make everyone feel better, then please remove it.

Comment: 'What is the best way to do this?' is a perfect example of what you're *not* doing. 'The best way' implies a criterion by which answers can be compared and the best one can be chosen. You've explicitly said you don't want a single best answer, you want a list. You should take a look at the [help centre](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to try to get an idea of what is required for an SE question.

Comment: For example, if your question was "where can I find a list of ways to achieve immortality"? There would be a finite answer, probably starting with [this link](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=5996)

Answer (score 2):

Turning yourself into a Construct. The Warforged from the Eberron setting are living constructs, and have no maximum age listed.

Comment: Also, Green Star Adept PrC.