# How would one go about becoming immortal without becoming a lich in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, druid

The character I am wanting this for is my Neutral Good druid who believes the best way to protect nature is to live as long as it lives. They only ways I have found are evil such as becoming a Lich or deity related.

The problem being in the world I am playing in all the deities have fallen and become mortal. Is there any way to become immortal, whether it's officially D&D or tried, tested, and backed-by-experience homebrew, without resorting to lichdom or deities?

Comment: You may be *very* interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37092/8610)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Part One: Read the Manual

This [link to an old handbook on immortality](http://bg-archive.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=5996.0), as well as its [updated and ported version](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1179.0) contain a fairly exhaustive list methods to gain immortality and pseudo-immortality, as well as their shortcomings and pitfalls. You may find what suits your purpose there.

### Part Two: Play as an Immortal Race

Elan ([SRD](http://dndsrd.net/psionicRaces.html#elans), Expanded Psionics Handbook), warforged (Eberron Campaign Setting) and killoren (Races of the Wild) are each timeless; though each ages through age categories, none has a maximum age. Being forest creatures, as well as fey, the killoren might suit your druidic purpose exactly.

Comment: I didn't even think of  races thank you so much!!

Comment: +1 for MMF immortality thread link. Also, it may be of interest to check out the Time of Troubles period from the FR campaign setting, as it dealt exactly with that situation: fallen Powers becoming mortals, and what happened as a result.

Comment: Since links tend to expire, would it be worth summarizing the content in this answer?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Perhaps. I'm not sure that summarizing the handbook is within the scope of this Q&A format... I guess I can without being *too* verbose.

Answer (score -1):

A good way if your looking to end your campaign but leave your character for future use is to have a trusted wizard clone you or if your ify on the clone thing you could ask to have sequester cast on you wich puts you in stasis until a set event ocures so you could have him have the set event be when the treees or forest creatures sense a disturbance in nature