# Is there any way to gain the endless special quality without carrying around a small necromantic magic item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Dragon Magazine #354 has a fairly well-known special quality called endless, which prevents aging and all its normal effects, but is unfortunately *not actually granted* by its associated feat, Wedded to History. Within the pages of this magazine, the only way to gain the quality (DM fiat aside) is to have someone cast *kissed by the ages* on you, and then to forevermore give up a magical item body slot and risk taking a penalty if you ever lose the item--which also radiates enough necromancy to make many NPCs very uneasy.

But what about methods *outside the pages of the magazine?* Is there any sort of feat, feature, or other special means by which someone can gain this extraordinary special quality, without needing to go around holding a pseudo-phylactery?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this question: [link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37092/living-forever-in-dd-via-spells)

Comment: ... and this [link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122510/how-would-one-go-about-becoming-immortal-without-becoming-a-lich-in-dd-3-5)

Comment: Although those links have lots of other good ways to avoid death, they don't actually mention a way to gain this particular special quality (which has a very different result when compared to just being able to revive or having to become an aberration/undead/etc.) without needing to hold onto an item that results from the *kissed by the ages* spell--other than the feat I mentioned, which by RAW doesn't actually work.

Comment: @47948201 Are you looking for *exactly* the ability **endless** except with no item requirement and for the ability to be actually called out as such? If so, you'll be out of luck as *Dragon* material from the *3e* era is almost never referenced in official texts and only rarely even referenced by other *Dragon* articles. There was no sequel to the article in question, for instance, and so far as I know the spell *kissed by the ages* and its corresponding special ability was never mentioned again in any publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There are only a few methods, each with their own level of... usability.

1. 5th level Illithid Savant gains the *Acquire Special Attack or Quality* Ability. This would obviously require you to be an illithid and find a target with the Endless quality to, ah, steal from.
2. The Sarruk's Manipulate Form ability can grant nearly any Special Quality.
3. True Mind Switch power can get you the body with the Endless trait, assuming the Quality stays with the body and doesn't go with the spirit.
4. Fusion + Astral Seed powers trick might be able to pull it off, again, assuming you can find a valid target.
5. Mindstealer drone has a special form of Change Shape that allows it to use an absorbed target's abilities. Again, you need a target to absorb. (Monster Mayhem articles)

Those are the ones that immediately come to mind.